# SOLR Parallel SQL casting issue

Tags: solr

Calling Solr Parallel SQL through REST `https://../api/solr/collection/sql?aggregationMode=facet`, with this query `SELECT query FROM collection WHERE filters_s='test:temp' AND rows=0`

I am getting this error:

```
    "result-set": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "EXCEPTION": "Conversion = '\"'",
                "EOF": true,
                "RESPONSE_TIME": 9
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I suspect the error is caused by `rows` which is of type `plong` (solr.LongPointField). Thoughts?

Comment: Reading the values of the fields without filters may help, then I would check the first and the second filter separately to know which one is causing the issue. Maybe you will find more information in the logs.

Comment: @EricLavault the type on the `rows` field is *solr.LongPointField* ...I can't seem to do a where clause on it.

Comment: Did you try to do a range query on it to see what happens ? Also, I'm not sure but maybe this is related to [docValues being required](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/parallel-sql-interface.html#fields) for that field. Try to add a limit clause to your query.